# Python scraping (Beautiful Soup) to obtain data from this HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
 <ul>
  <li>
    <div class="c_logo_box">
     <a href="money-transfer-companies/ria-money-transfer/"><img src="http://www.compareremit.com/uploads/ria-logo11.png" style="height:57px;width:147px;" alt="RIA Money Transfer"></a>
     <span class="rs"> <span class="txt13">&#8377;</span> 61.24</span>
       </div>
  </li>
 ...
```

I wish to scrap the **name** from 'alt = Ria Money Transfer' and **rate** from span 61.24.

So far I have this Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.compareremit.com')
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for rate in soup.find_all('li', re.compile('money')):
print rate.text
```

It gives me nothing. Could someone tell me what am I missing? Also, I'm having trouble visualizing which element I'm support to look for in the for loop search, could you clarify in general how to know what to specify as a condition in for loop in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is logically not correct. You can do this in multiple ways, try this code

#!/usr/bin/python

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.compareremit.com')
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for rate in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"c_logo_box"}):
    print rate.a.img['alt'] 
    print rate.span.text
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to reach the element. One option is to rely on the `a` tag, `href` of which contains the `ria-money-transfer` part, then get the [following `span` element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) containing the rate:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.compareremit.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

link = soup.find('div', class_='c_logo_box').find('a', href=re.compile(r'ria-money-transfer'))
print(link.img.get('alt'))

rate = link.find_next_sibling('span').text.split(' ')[-1]
print(rate)
```

Prints:

```
RIA Money Transfer
61.24
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error executing this: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./all_.py", line 11, in <module>
    link = soup.find('div', class_='c_logo_box').find('a', href=re.compile(r'ria-money-transfer'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'"

Comment: @intellikid ok, what if you replace `BeautifulSoup(response.content)` with `BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")`?

Comment: Nope, still an error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delnow.py", line 9, in <module>
    link = soup.find('div', class_='c_logo_box').find('a', href=re.compile(r'ria-money-transfer'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'"